# Do Network Services Come with New Install?

Tags: networking, services

I just installed a new Windows 7 vm, and had this same thing with a Ubuntu I installed a while back.  When I scan the machine from other vm's, all 1000 ports are closed.  However, with my Windows XP machine, I had already had things like SMB open, etc.  I've googled this, but I don't know if it's too vague.  Do you have to install services on the vm first, or should it naturally auto run things like smb/msrpc, netbios etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Stealth Mode in Windows Firewall with Advanced Security](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd448557%28WS.10%29.aspx) TechNet article:

> **Stealth Mode** is a mechanism in Windows Firewall that helps prevent
>   malicious users from discovering information about network computers
>   and the services that they run.
>
> It is common for an attacker to use an automated scanning process to
>   send query packets to a range of IP addresses. For each IP address,
>   the scanning process sends packets to a range of port numbers, and the
>   response packets are used to identify the services that are installed
>   on the computer. For example, if a computer responds to a UDP query
>   with an ICMP unreachable packet, or to a TCP query with a reset
>   message, then an attacker is able to determine the existence of a
>   computer at that IP address and an open port in Windows Firewall that
>   can be used to reach the computer. The attacker can then use this
>   information to attempt to exploit vulnerabilities.
>
> Stealth Mode in Windows Firewall with Advanced Security is designed to
>   help protect against this kind of attack. Stealth Mode blocks outgoing
>   ICMP unreachable and TCP reset messages for a port when no application
>   is listening on that port.
>
> Stealth Mode is enabled by default on computers that are running
>   Windows Vista®, Windows Server® 2008, Windows® 7, and Windows Server®
>   2008 R2.
>
> **Important**
>
> Network packets dropped by the stealth Mode feature are not logged.

The **Port Scanning Prevention Filter** is what Windows Firewall uses for its Stealth Mode mechanism. This filter is always active in the filtering platform providing additional protection to a node in a network even if the firewall profiles have been turned off.

By default for an IPv4 connection the NetBIOS setting is obtained from the DHCP server. You can change it to enable or disable NetBIOS over TCP/IP by opening **ncpa.cpl**, right-clicking the connection you want to configure, selecting Properties, selecting IPv4, clicking on Properties, on the General tab clicking on Advanced and going to the WINS tab:

[image: 1]

The Remote Procedure Call (rpcss) service is enabled by default, as are both Server (lanmanserver) and Workstation (lanmanworkstation) services (check by opening **services.msc**). For instructions to enable or disable SMBv1, SMBv2 and SMBv3 check [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2696547/).

Comment: I would upvote but I don't have enough points lol